# Using grep to find two letters in specific order in R

Tags: r, regex

To get started

```
words <- c("bait", "gait","quit","suit","wait","spit","twit")
```

I would like to write a grep() function that returns words that rhyme with "it" ... in this case it would return:

"quit", "spit", and "twit"

but not

"bait", "suit", or "wait"

So far I am stuck on one that fails to distinguish:

```
grep("[^a][i][t]$", words, value = T)
```

And another that erroneously removes "quit"

```
grep("[^su|a][i][t]$", words, value =T )
```

I'm sure there is an easy out here, but I'm not seeing it. 
Thanks!

Comment: Realistically, this cannot be done using `grep`. It's not a linguistic tool. I cannot think of a sober way using regex to distinguish between words that rhyme and non-rhyme words, e.g. [this site shows 228 words](https://www.rhymezone.com/r/rhyme.cgi?Word=it&typeofrhyme=perfect&org1=syl&org2=l&org3=y) that rhyme with it.

Comment: You could also try the `rhymer` package. It won't grab slang words though (i'm not sure if twit counts as slang). `words[words %in% rhymer::get_rhyme("it", limit = 50, return_type = "vector", num_syl = 1)]`

Comment: @AndS. awesome. This should be an answer. Definitively going to upvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you want to specify that a final 'it' is either preceded by a consonant (non-vowel) or by 'qu'.  So ...

```
grep("(qu|[^aeiou])it$", words, value=T)
[1] "quit" "spit" "twit"
```